# PHP Login Script Not Linking With Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script and when I go to the website link(http://kodle.co.uk/login.php) the script comes back with this:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using >password: NO) in /home/hkode/public_html/dbconnect.php on line 12
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db(): Access denied for user 'hkode'@'localhost' (using >password: NO) in /home/hkode/public_html/dbconnect.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db(): A link to the server could not be established in >/home/hkode/public_html/dbconnect.php on line 13
> Connection failed : Access denied for user 'hkode'@'localhost' (using password: >NO)

The **DBCONNECT.php** script is as follows:

```
<?php

// this will avoid mysql_connect() deprecation error.
error_reporting( ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE );
// but I strongly suggest you to use PDO or MySQLi.

define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
define('DBUSER', 'root');
define('DBPASS', '');
define('DBNAME', 'login_base');

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$dbcon = mysql_select_db(DBNAME);

if ( !$conn ) {
    die("Connection failed : " . mysql_error());
}

if ( !$dbcon ) {
    die("Database Connection failed : " . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: there is no password set

Comment: You create a connection $conn...but then select a db on $dbcon (which I don't see set anywhere). That doesn't look like it'd work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your database and check if user root actually does not require a password. If it does then insert it as a third parameter in the empty single quotes below. Now use the code below and you will be just fine. Happy new year.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('REPLACE_THIS_WITH_IP_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_SERVER', 'root', ''); 
if (!$con) { 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
mysql_select_db("login_base", $con); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
define('DBPASS', '');
```

You want to replace `''` with `'youractualpassword'`

Then change

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
```

to

```
 mysql_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS);
```

On a further note the comment

```
// this will avoid mysql_connect() deprecation error.
error_reporting( ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE );
// but I strongly suggest you to use PDO or MySQLi.
```

Suggest you don't use these methods. You should only do this if you absolutely know what you are doing, which seems like you do not.

I highly suggest using something like laracasts to learn php.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$conn = mysql_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER);
$dbcon = mysql_select_db(DBNAME, $conn);
```

**Edited** Check all passwords

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the password is not right for user root also i would suggest you to use the constants for connecting to mysql which u have already defined.
i would rewrite connection statement and subsequent statement  something like this

```
$conn = mysql_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    if ( !$conn ) { 
    die("Connection failed : " . mysql_error());
}else{ // connection succesful
   $dbcon = mysql_select_db(DBNAME);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql is deprecated you have to use mysqli or pdo. example of mysqli is ...

```
 $hostname= "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "your_database_name";
 $con = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password,$dbname);

 if ($con->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
 } 
 $sql = "your_query";

 if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   echo "On query result is successfull";
 } else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}
$con->close();
```